# Subscribing to Observable in async calls not working [Angular2]

Tags: typescript, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have a method *getData()* in my service.ts as below. This returns an Observable. Another service *ApiService* also has a method *get()* which also returns an Observable.

```
    getData(args, parentKey?):any {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            this.apiService.get(args).subscribe(
                response => {
                    observer.next({
                        data: response['data'],
                        status: ($.isEmptyObject(response) ? false : true) 
                    });
                },
                error => console.log("error : ", error),
                () => console.log("finished")
            );
        });
    }
```

I am trying to reuse this getData() method in **asynchronous** API calls to be made from my component. See below:

```
this.myService.getData({
    url: 'apiUrl1',
    method: 'Method1',
    parameters: {}
}).subscribe(response => {
    if (response['status']) {
        console.log('Processed apiUrl1');
    }
});
this.myService.getData({
    url: 'apiUrl2',
    method: 'Method2',
    parameters: {}
}).subscribe(response => {
    if (response['status']) {
        console.log('Processed apiUrl2');
    }
});
this.myService.getData({
    url: 'apiUrl3',
    method: 'Method3',
    parameters: {}
}).subscribe(response => {
    if (response['status']) {
        console.log('Processed apiUrl3');
    }
});
```

**Bug:**
But what happens is that the getData-observable is always subscribed into apiUrl3.

I need each getData() to be subscribed to individually. Can someone please help me out?

**Expected Result:**

> Processed apiUrl1
>
> Processed apiUrl2
>
> Processed apiUrl3

Comment: I read through all stackoverflow explanations and other resources on to what Observables and Promises really are. But this is not working in case of my asynchronous calls. Can you please help what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure where is your problem, but this is more clear and maybe will work.

```
getData(args, parentKey?):any {
    this.apiService.get(args)
        .map(response => {
                data: response['data'],
                status: ($.isEmptyObject(response) ? false : true)
        })
        .do(() => console.log("finished"))
        .catch(error => console.log("error : ", error));
}
```